# Can I change placeholder text with CSS or jQuery depending on the browser width?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my Bootstrap top menu (Rails 4 application) I have a search boz where users can search for products, and therefore my placeholder text is something like:

*Find product, e.g. Macbook Pro...*

When the browser is resized to e.g. small mobile format, the text is too long. So I would like the text to only be something like:

*Find product...*

I am using Rails localization, so I would prefer to be able to have localized text instead of putting something directly into the css file. So maybe it is possible with jQuery, although I suppose it is a bit more heavy solution. Any ideas?

My placeholder CSS looks like this:

```
@media (max-width: 614px) and (min-width: 1px) {
  .top-menu input {
    width: 230px;
  }

  .top-menu input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #6b7279;
  }

  .top-menu input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #6b7279;
  }

  .top-menu input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #6b7279;
  }
}
```

Comment: As a pure CSS solution you could follow this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176102/swap-placeholder-text-based-on-resolution-media-query/18176310#18176310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $(window).on("resize", function (e) {
        var w = e.target.innerWidth;
        var input = $("input[class=top-menu]");
        return input.css({
            "color": "#6b7279",
            "width": "230px"
            })
            .attr("placeholder"
                  , (w > 1 && w < 614) 
                  ? "Find a product..." 
                  : "Find product, e.g. Macbook Pro...")
    }).resize()
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/vfu3cdwb/4/

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. In this case `.my_textarea` is the class attached to the `textarea` `html` tag.

```
 $('.my_textarea').each(function() {
        $(this).data('placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder'));
    });

    function changePlaceholder() {
        if( $(window).width() <= 640){
            $('.my_textarea').attr('placeholder','Find product...');
        } else {
            $('.my_textarea').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).data('placeholder'));
            });
        }   
    }

    $(window).resize( changePlaceholder ).trigger('resize');
```