# Change form initally selected option via CSS media query

Tags: html, css, forms, responsive-design

In order to have a selection dropdown text fit smaller screen, I have been asked to change the text of the initially selected option for smaller screens. This page was done with bootstrap and the initial selected option is the question itself (disabled as a valid selection).

I could use Javascript to accomplish this. A CSS-only solution that's quick and works is to duplicate the select element and have one class for mobile and one class for larger screens, where each class just displays or hides the element. (Following the logic in 
[Swap placeholder text based on resolution (media query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176102/swap-placeholder-text-based-on-resolution-media-query))

Ideally, I would would apply such classes only to the option elements rather than repeat the whole select element.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <select name="budget" id="" class="form-control input-lg">
        <option class="long"  value="" disabled selected>WHAT IS YOUR TIMELINE TO COMPLETE THIS PROJECT?</option>
        <option class="short" value="" disabled selected>WHAT'S YOUR TIMELINE?</option>
        <option>I'm not sure</option>
        <option>3 months</option>
        <option>6 months</option>
        <option>1 year</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Where the CSS for the mobile media query is the following (reversed for other displays):

```
.long {
    display: none;
}
.short {
    display: inherit;
}
```

While this succeeds in hiding the dropdown option, the selected attribute is still recognized, so "WHAT'S YOUR TIMELINE?" will always be the initial question displayed, even if the option itself is not displayed in the dropdown.

Again, I am just going with a solution of duplicating the select element, but for my own knowledge, I am wondering if there is a HTML/CSS-only solution that would say "in mobile, option 2 is initially selected (and visible; option 1 is hidden); otherwise, option 1 is selected (and option 2 is hidden)".

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML/CSS solution, add both classes and create a media query that targets mobile.  For Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .short {
        display: block;
        //shows these styles on mobile
    }

    .long {
        display:none;
        //hides these styles on mobile
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <select name="budget" id="" class="form-control input-lg">
        <option class="short"  value="">Mobile Text</option>
        <option class="short" value="">Mobile Text</option>
        <option class="long">Text for anything but mobile</option>
        <option class="long">Text for anything but mobile</option>
        <option class="long">Text for anything but mobile</option>
        <option class="long">Text for anything but mobile</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Check out my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwGmZO)

Comment: Thanks, Justin. I edited my question to emphasize that I am trying to set the initially selected value based on a media query. I've forked your codepen to better illustrate what I mean (thanks for setting it up).
http://codepen.io/bullcitydave/pen/vEXmpe
I can hide the 'LONG VALUE FOR NON-MOBILE' option for < 320px, but I want to somehow also get rid of the **selected** attribute so that 'SHORT VALUE FOR MOBILE' is initially selected. I could do this with Javascript but wonder if it is possible with CSS only.

Comment: You could try writting an if() in SASS to check for the media query min-width, if it is, set .short [attr=selected].  I think that could work, would be easier to do with js.